# How does the ActionListener work?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I found similar code to the following on Oracle's website. I stripped some irrelevant stuff regarding layout for space reasons.

```
private JTextField textField;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public TextDemo()
    {
        textField = new JTextField(5);
        //This causes a leaking this in constructor warning...
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        //code here for layout and to add the textfield to the panel
    }


    private static int ctr = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.out.println(ctr++);           
    }

}
```

So I made a print statement to print and increment a counter to check when this actionListener is detecting an action.

I was wondering:

1. Is the only action that triggers this method the enter button?
2. In my constructor where I attached `this` to the action listener of the `textField` object, what exactly happens?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to have your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces except for the most simplistic toy programs. In other words, better not to have your GUI implement ActionListener and then pass `this` in to your `addActionListener(...)` method. Better to either use an anonymous inner class (you can look that up) or a separate class since it is much easier to maintain and extend such code.

Comment: Very much easier to read.

Comment: Going even one step beyond Hovercraft's excellent advice, if the action is something serious that might be shared amongst various Components, or might need to be disabled in certain circumstances, strongly consider using an [javax.swing.Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  e.g. your "Save" might be attached to both a Button and a Menu, and ideally would be disabled if there is nothing to save.

Comment: And in addition to Hovercraft's comment: don't polute your API. The fact that you're using an ActionListener is an implementation detail and shouldn't show in the API/ Javadoc. Only if a class can be used as an ActionListener elsewhere, it sould implement the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action event occurs, whenever an action is performed by the user.

Examples: When the user clicks a button, chooses a menu item, presses Enter in a text field. The result is that an actionPerformed message is sent to all action listeners that are registered on the relevant component.

this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this

```
 textField.addActionListener(this); // registering actionlistener
```

Capturing the action event

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    System.out.println(ctr++);   //perform some action on click        
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

As suggested by Hovercraft Full Of Eels you can also use annonymous inner class as below

```
 textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              //do something
              }  
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Typically one uses a DocumentListener for a JTextField. It tells lots more interesting information about what is going on. It actually ties to the document (a sort of Model) that lies behind the GUI field.

Now:

Q1 - It's hard to figure out which mouse and keyboard actions cause the various events on the Swing screen components. As I remember,  may be it for `ActionPerformed`. But there can be custom code added to a sub-class of a `JTextField` that causes an action event to fire for anything you want. You DO have to be careful if you do this.

Q2: The Listener object is stored in a list of all the objects that want to know when the text field has that action event occur. When it occurs, the text field calls the `actionPerformed()` method on all the objects in its listener list.

You might want to do some research on the **Observer Pattern**. That is the a name often used for bits of code that do this sort of thing. It can be used in many situations. The key is that it loosely couples the listener and the listenee (observer and observed). The object listening only has to tell the object to which it is listening that it want to be notified in certain cases. The object that is being listened-to keeps a list of all the various objects listening and what events they want to be informed of. That's all the connection and with the use of simple interfaces, it can be programmed simply.

Comment: I would argue against your statement about "typically" using a DocumentListener. If the coder wishes changes to be registered on enter press, then he'd use an ActionListener. If he wanted to listen for data entered prior to it displaying in the text component, he'd use a DocumentFilter. He'd only use a DocumentListener if desiring to listen for changes while data is being entered but after it has been added to the text component.

Comment: Fair enough, my friend, @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

> Is the only action that triggers this method the enter button?

Yes. For `JTextFields` an `ActionEvent` is dispatched by pressing ENTER.

> In my constructor where I attached this to the action listener of the textField object, what exactly happens?

You register the `ActionListener` with the component. When an `ActionEvent` is triggered it dispatches an `ActionEvent` where `actionPerformed` is invoked, passing it the details of the source object in the `ActionEvent`.

The preferred approach for the implementation of `ActionListeners` is to use a separate anonymous listener per component or a single concrete [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for shared functionality.

Comment: So in this case, the ActionListener is registered to the component `TextDemo`, which is a `JPanel`. So by default, when I register a `JPanel` or any `JComponent`, the default action that will trigger the Listener is the enter button?

Comment: Well rather the button is registered with the listener which is `TextDemo` because that is where `ActionListener` is implemented. You wouldnt register a `JPanel` as it wouldnt be possible to generate `ActionEvents` for that container (but you could set the default button for a `JRootPane`)

Comment: Oh right. My typo. I couldn't find any documentation as to why or if this is infact true, but Im guessing that the default is just the enter button then.

Comment: Yes, for `JTextFields` that is how `ActionEvents` are dispatched...by pressing ENTER

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK, yes. The listener is called when enter is pressed while the textfield has the focus.
2. The current object, being constructed, is added to the list of ActionListeners of the text field, so that when enter is pressed in the text field, the current object's `actionPerformed()` method is called. It's generally a bad practice to pass an object not being fully constructed to another object, because the other object could call it back directly and the object wouldn't be functional, since not fully constructed yet.